# JQueryMobile: Adding Button inside a ListView

Tags: listview, button, jquery-mobile

I am adding some elements inside a ListView, I know it is possible in the current one but what I do really need is I want to have control over the size and position of a button in the row.

currently i have this [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Rqwq/) code.

js code

```
$("#ui-mato").css({
    'position':'relative',
    'left':'70.0px',
    'top':'0px',
    'width':'150.0px',
    'height':'38.0px',
    'line-height':'38.0px'
});
```

The problem is though I can freely move the button I cant move it to the top part though I set the top property to 0, it doesnt work. Also Is it possible to make the particular ListView row bigger?

If anyone can help me please. see my JFiddle. Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:**

I found a way to make it stick to the ceiling of the row by assigning negative value like -20. but I dont understand why it has to be negative. And one more thing, do anyone know how to adjust the height of a row?

**UPDATE 2**

I think I fould the solution. Thanks Phill for some ideas
here it is [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Rqwq/19/)

Comment: Would the split button list work? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/lists/lists-split.html

Comment: actually what I neede is like this http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/lists/lists-forms.html. But I need an item at a particular position... for example I like a button placed in x=20 and y=30 and another item at different position inside the List.

Comment: Playing around, is this something you could use? http://jsfiddle.net/3Rqwq/16/

Comment: thank you Phill for this. Its something like that but what i really need is something like for example... I have a row with 300 height. and inside it there is a button placed in x=20 and y=20 with a width and height of 100. and then I want to place another button lets say at x=20 and y =150 with same height.... and so on...

Comment: thanks Phill... i think i found the solution. i needed to set a div inside a the list and set the position to relative... and put my items inside that div with the absolute positioning.

Comment: glad to help. You should post your solution as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I made. [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Rqwq/22/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use grid in li, you can control the position by percentage of grid.